# Can a tor exit node know the ip of .onion sites?

Tags: tor

I am just wondering about this since I heard that tor exit nodes know the ip of the website the user is visiting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a Tor exit node does not know the IP of a .onion site. The only node that knows the real IP of a .onion site is a special node called [guard node](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#EntryGuards). It's the first node the hidden service connects to, so it knows the real IP.

Answer (score 2):

You already have an accepted answer, but I'm going to add a clarification anyway.

When connecting with a hidden service (*.onion*), there is **no exit node at all**! Exit nodes are gateways to the normal (*non Tor*) Internet. Hidden services (*.onion*) don't exit, therefore no exit node.

Guard nodes are entries (*although all nodes are bidirectional*) to Tor. So yes the guard node knows the real IP of the connecting computer but it knows nothing about *.onion* hidden services. The guard node cannot identify and locate *.onion* hidden services.